# Array, toString?

Tags: java, arrays, return, tostring

So what im trying to do is print out this array.

```
    coins[0] = new Coin(CoinName.PENNY, 2011);
    coins[1] = new Coin(CoinName.DIME, 1952);
    coins[2] = new Coin(CoinName.DOLLAR, 1999);
    coins[3] = new Coin(CoinName.NICKEL, 2004);
    coins[4] = new Coin(CoinName.DIME, 1952);
    coins[5] = new Coin(CoinName.DOLLAR, 1945);
    coins[6] = new Coin(CoinName.PENNY, 2011);
    coins[7] = new Coin(CoinName.QUARTER, 1961);
    coins[8] = new Coin(CoinName.NICKEL, 1983);
    coins[9] = new Coin(CoinName.FIFTY_CENT, 1963);
```

but I know i can use the Arrays.toString method, but I cannot use it this time. 
I have to use my own method named

```
public String toString()
```

this is how it needs to be set up completely, and the instructions for how to do it are in a comment.

```
//the standard toString method that returns a String listing all the coins in the jar,   in their current order
public String toString()
{
    return ???;

}
```

the initialization of the array is in a method called CoinJar(Coin[] coins) but is within the same class.

Im not sure if im asking this question right, if you guys need any specifics please ask.

Comment: `return "What have you tried?";`

Comment: @RohitJain My comment vote limit for today is already gone, but this one is epic...

Comment: Im not even sure where to start. becuase I cant put a loop inside of a return statement can I?

Comment: What about `return Arrays.toString(coins);` ?

Comment: @jlordo. He can't use that.

Comment: it returns null still :\

Comment: @RohitJain: I've understood: He can't use `Arrays.toString()`, because he has to write his own `toString()` method. IMHO, this doesn't mean ha can't use `Arrays.toString()` in his `toString()` ;)

Comment: You might need to have a method inside the Coin class as well, probably named `toString`, which returns the coin's name and year as a string. Then loop through the array of Coins, adding each Coin's string together, and return that one big string. Or, if implementing `toString()` in the Coin class makes it possible, use `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: actually i get this [LCoin;@45e881b6 not null lol. sorry.

Comment: I already have a method inside the coin class named that, that works perfectly.

Comment: @MarcusScaffidi: Either you follow a tutorial and learn about loops, or you do what I've written in my comment above.

Comment: I tried that. But im not sure if the way i tried it was right.  do you just return Arrays.toString(coins);??

Comment: @MarcusScaffidi: Yes, exactly as I posted. You could save it to a `String` variable first, but you don't need to do that. `return Arrays.toString(coins);` is just fine.

Comment: Alright.. well im still getting [LCoin;@6e34b350..as the output this is how i should call it from my driver right?  System.out.println(coins1.toString()); Coins 1 is just a array i created in the driver.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coins1));`

Comment: okay, so now im getting an array of nulls. lol :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED WITH A COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

Your Coin class should look something like this:

```
public class Coin {
    private CoinName coinName;
    private int year;

    public Coin(CoinName coinName, int year) {
        this.coinName = coinName;
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return coinName + " " + year;
    }
}
```

The method you don't know what to put in is in there, I made this class to test the answer I'm posting:

```
public class CoinContainer {
    private Coin[] coins;

    public CoinContainer() {  
        coins = new Coin[10];

        coins[0] = new Coin(CoinName.PENNY, 2011);
        coins[1] = new Coin(CoinName.DIME, 1952);
        coins[2] = new Coin(CoinName.DOLLAR, 1999);
        coins[3] = new Coin(CoinName.NICKEL, 2004);
        coins[4] = new Coin(CoinName.DIME, 1952);
        coins[5] = new Coin(CoinName.DOLLAR, 1945);
        coins[6] = new Coin(CoinName.PENNY, 2011);
        coins[7] = new Coin(CoinName.QUARTER, 1961);
        coins[8] = new Coin(CoinName.NICKEL, 1983);
        coins[9] = new Coin(CoinName.FIFTY_CENT, 1963);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String myString = "";

        for(Coin coin : coins) {
            myString += coin + "\n";
        }

        return myString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinContainer coinContainer = new CoinContainer();

        System.out.println(coinContainer);
    }
}
```

Finally, for the sake of having a complete answer, your CoinName Enum probably looks something like this:

```
public enum CoinName {
    PENNY,
    DIME,
    DOLLAR,
    NICKEL,
    QUARTER,
    FIFTY_CENT
}
```

I tested it and everything works. Here is the output I'm getting:

```
PENNY 2011
DIME 1952
DOLLAR 1999
NICKEL 2004
DIME 1952
DOLLAR 1945
PENNY 2011
QUARTER 1961
NICKEL 1983
FIFTY_CENT 1963
```

Comment: I tried this, still got something like this --- [LCoin;@45e881b6

Comment: @Marcus That's because you haven't overridden thr ToString method in the Coin class as well.

Comment: all you do for that is to type @Override above it right? becuase i did that.

Comment: That's my mistake. I'm on my phone now so I can't verify this (I will in an hour), but try coinName.name() instead of just coinName in the toString method in the Coin class.

Comment: @MarcusScaffidi I just tested everything in Eclipse and it works without the need for the ".name()" part. Are you sure you have overridden both the toString method in Coin and in your class that contains the "coins" array?

Comment: I still get an array full of nulls.

Comment: @Marcus See my updated answer. Also, I don't get how you can "still" get an array full of nulls since you posted earlier that you were getting "[LCoin;@45e881b6", which is not null.

Comment: Im sorry, I am fairly new to this, and im trying my best. Ive been getting mixed outputs with everything I try, what im getting now is the [LCoin;@5e875dee. I think its doing that becuase i never called the method coinContainer before i tried to print it out. Im trying to call what you used coinContainer from a driver, would that be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In you coin class, override toString() to something like this :

```
public String toString()
{
    return this.coinName+ " " + this.year;
}
```

and to print the array contents you can do something like this

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer();
    // or you could use this too...    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder(); in a performance intensive system, where there is no need of synchronization this would be a little better.
    for(int index = 0; index < coins.length; index++ )
    {
        st.append("Coin "+index+" : "+coins[index].toString());
    }  
    return st.toString(); 

}
```

Comment: Why `StringBuffer`? Use `StringBuilder` if you don't need synchronization.

Comment: to be on the safe side... what if he uses this code in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Even in a multi threaded environment, this operation is atomic, so no need of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @codeMan: I don't think someone writing multithreaded code will ask: How do I write `toString()`...

Comment: @jlordo I get ur point. Common guys... there is no much significant difference in performance between StringBuffer and StringBuilder, unless he is building a real time system... on the same lines of jlordo I am assuming that he is not building a RTS either..

Comment: Its nothing that complex lol. All it is, is a jar filled with coins. and im trying to print out what the coin is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that CoinName is an Enum, so your Coin object should override toString method

To be sure that you override it correctly (so code will not compile if you don't), you must annotate method with @Override.

Method could look like this:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("[Name: ")
                .append(name.getName())
                .append(", Year: ")
                .append(year)
                .append("]")
                .toString();
    }
```

This will print nice output:

```
[[Name: PENNY, Year: 2011], [Name: DIME, Year: 1952]... ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Overload default `toString` method in `Coin` class. Then in your own `toString` method loop over `coins` array and simply

```
public String toString {
    private String s = "";
    for(int i =0; i < coins.length; i++)
        s += coins(i) + ", ";

    return s
}
```

As suggested, if performance is necessary use `StringBuilder` instead!

Comment: You're not returning a `String`.

Comment: Do you ever forget to insert a return? Pathetic!

Comment: String concatenation in a loop: do we like that?

Comment: @marianoc84 if you **at least** test your code before posting it, you won't forget either :).

Comment: @marianoc84: No, because the compiler tells me in case I do. Please use an IDE when you write code. It will tell you about your syntax errors. There are at least 3 more in the code posted.

Comment: @jlordo: How many times, we say: This is not a site for ready-code but for concepts. The real concept to understand is the toString override. Imho...

Comment: @ppeterka66 no we don't like, but in this post performance was not a concern. We should use the common sense when answer to someone...